# Time Reversal Bulk Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, time-reversal-symmetry

This questions is from pages 68 and 69 of: http://fizipedia.bme.hu/images/1/14/Topological_insulators.pdf

For a lattice, time reversal invariance of the bulk corresponds to the equation (Eqn 6.11):
$$
\mathcal{TH(-k)T^{-1}}=\mathcal{H(k)}
$$

Given a system corresponding to $H(k)$, they claim the following "doubled" system has time reversal symmetry for $\mathcal{T}=i\tau_{y}K$, where $\tau$ is for the new degree of freedom:

$$
H_{2}(k)=
\begin{bmatrix}
H(k) & 0\\
0 & H^*(-k)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The proof runs (Eqn 6.14):

$$
\mathcal{T}H_{2}(k)\mathcal{T^{-1}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
H^*(-k) & 0\\
0 & H(k)\\
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
=H_{2}(k)
$$

I follow the calculations, but how does the last equation show the first?  The minus k?

Comment: The thing sandwiched between $\mathcal{T}$s in your last equation should've been $H_{2}(-k)$ (this is how you get a -k in the upper left value in your matrix! Otherwise the equality as written just isn't true.) and then it's trivially a special case of the first line.

Comment: I don't think so.  Below Eqn 6.13, it is explained $KH(k)K=H^{*}(-k)$